# Run function when Dictionary contents changes

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, dictionary

I have a few `ListViews` that depend on the contents of `Dictionary<string,string>`s. I also have one function per dictionary for updating its associated `ListView`. However, these have to be called manually and this can cause all kinds of problems if forgotten. Is it possible to call a function whenever any value within a dictionary is changed?

My initial thoughts were to use `DataBinding` but `Listview` doesn't support this in `WinForms` or to raise some custom events but I wouldn't even know where to begin with that.

Is there a simple way to acheive this?

Just for clarification I'm talking about something that has this effect:

```
Dictionary[key] = "this";  //Automatically runs UpdateDictionaryBox();
Dictionary.Add(key,value); //The same
Dictionary.Remove(key);    //And again
```

Comment: Something like a [`ObservableDictionary`](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/) ?

Comment: Why not using `DataGridView` bound to a `BindingList<T>` where T implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: Normally you can avoid such things by encapsulation and single responsibility classes. If you had a class that holds this dictionary and this would be private, no one could access it but this class. Then you could provide properties/methods to change, add or remove items. This is the only place where you need to handle this, f.e. by triggering a custom event that can be handled, there you could call `UpdateDictionaryBox`

Comment: @TimSchmelter so essentially just create a shell class which keeps track of the dictionary and the control, then get and set through that?

Comment: @JamesHughes: Yes, a class which only responsibility is to store and maintain this dictionary (or related stuff). This can be initialized in the controller class. This "dictionary-class" doesn't know your `UpdateDictionaryBox`, actually it should not know it because it's not it's job. So you need a way to notify the controller, the normal way is to use a custom event. Then it gets notified and you call the method in the event-handler. It's not really simple but clean, safe and resusable.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you. If you would write that up as an answer I will happily accept it. Unless you're happy for me to do that for you.

Comment: Also you may want to take a look at this post: [How to display a dictionary using DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566268/how-to-display-a-dictionary-using-datagridview)

Comment: Thanks @RezaAghaei, unfortunately my UI design has been slightly dictated to me. A `DataGridView` isn't what they want, but that post is useful for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

All credit to Tim Schmelter as his comment led me to this solution!

Essentially, the easiest method is to create a wrapper class around the `Dictionary<string,string>` and the `ListView` then use this to implement all of the dictionary methods that are needed and call the update at the end of `.Add`, `.Remove` `[key] = value` etc.

This way, once the class is implemented correctly, it emulates data binding.

My resulting class is:

```
class DictionaryListViewPseudoBinder : IEnumerable
{
    private ListView ListView { get; }
    private Dictionary<string,string> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public DictionaryListViewPseudoBinder(ListView listView)
    {
        ListView = listView;
        Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key) ? Dictionary[key] : "";
        }
        set
        {
            if (Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                Dictionary[key] = value;
                RepopulateListView();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dictionary does not contain key " + key + " aborting...");
            }
        }
    }
    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            Dictionary.Add(key, value);
            RepopulateListView();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The Entry \"{0}\" already exists in {1}",key,ListView.Name));
        }
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        if (Dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            Dictionary.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return Dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsKVP(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp)
    {
        if (!Dictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return Dictionary[kvp.Key] == kvp.Value;
        }
    }
    private void RepopulateListView()
    {
        ListView.Items.Clear();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in Dictionary)
        {
            ListView.Items.Add(kvp.Key).SubItems.Add(kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

NB: The above is not fully tested yet and not all methods are fully implemented at this time, but it shows the general framework necessary for this functionality.

Comment: Don't use the contains check with a dictionary, it causes two lookups one for the contains and one for the operation inside the if. Use the try methods (TryAdd , etc.) Instead.